# Using for LOOP function and grouping columns to columns

Tags: ampscript, data, dataextensions, loop

A question out to the group that I hope someone might be able to shed some light on, I've made a custom report that is pulling from multiple data extensions to populate results - clicks, click rate, opens, open rates etc. This summary section is working as expected.

The 2nd section of the report I want to list the links that were clicked and the subscribers that clicked them, i've found some FOR Loop code that pulls in all the links and all the subscribers but I need to A) format the links and subscribers so they list downwards and B) group the subscribers to the links they clicked, can anyone give some pointers?

The information on the links and the subscribers that clicked are all in one data extension that is updated through SQL.

An example of my set up for this section is:

```
%%[

VAR

@CustomerEmailAddress, @rows, @rows2, @Linkname

SET @CustomerEmailAddress = Lookup("SingleCampaignClickPerCustomer", "CustomerEmailAddress", "ConsultantID", @ConsultantID)

SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("SingleCampaignClickPerCustomer",0, "CustomerEmailAddress Asc", "ConsultantID", @ConsultantID)

SET @rows2 = LookupOrderedRows("SingleCampaignClickPerCustomer",0, "LinkName Asc", "CustomerEmailAddress", @CustomerEmailAddress)

]%%
```

Then actioning the code:

```
%%[
FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows2)

DO

SET @row = Row(@rows2, @i)

SET @Linkname = Field(@row,"Linkname")
]%%

td><font face="verdana" size="2">%%=v(@Linkname)=%%</font><br>%%[ NEXT ]%%

%%[
FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows)

DO

SET @row = Row(@rows, @i)

SET @CustomerEmailAddress = Field(@row,"CustomerEmailAddress")
]%%

td valign="top"><font size="2" face="verdana">%%=v(@CustomerEmailAddress)=%% <br /></font>%%[ NEXT ]%%</td></tr
/table
```

Am I not finalising the loop function properly perhaps? If anyone out there can share some advise it would be incredibly helpful,

Thanks!

Comment: What are the results of the toolbar validation?

Comment: What columns are in the SingleCampaignClickPerCustomer data extension?

Comment: Where is @ConsultantID set?

Comment: You might want to reference the loop variables in your NEXT statements, e.g. %%[ NEXT @i ]%%

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for reading. Sorry my question perhaps itsn't clear, I've only included the variables I'm referring too.  ConsultantID is set with the other VARs for the top section.

The SingleCampaignClickPerCustomer DE has ConsultantID, ConsultantEmailAddress, SchedTime, EmailSubject, LinkName, CustomerEmailAddress and EmailName columns.

I'll try your suggestion with adding the variable to the next statement, Thanks!

Comment: Adding the @ i into the statement worked a treat...Still stuck on grouping the subscribers to the link though:
Link A - subscriber 1,2,3,4,5 clicked
Link B - subscriber 6,7,8,9 clicked etc

Am going to try the lookuprow from the help pages 

If i want to link all the customeremailaddresses to the link would i write it as:

'SET @ rows = LookupOrderedRows("LinksSummary",1, "LinkName Asc", "ConsultantID", @ ConsultantID)'

'Set @ rows2 = LookupOrderedRows("LinksSummaryTest",0,"CustomerEmailAddress","LinkName",Field(@ row,"LinkName"))'